# ScrollView: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I got a ScrollView with many Views and if i start the activity i got this after some scrolling:

```
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:3654)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:618)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.getFocusables(View.java:3612)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:109)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:93)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:476)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:3547)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4662)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:945)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1129)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isActive(InputMethodManager.java:542)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4173)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6933)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:7039)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1415)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
04-10 20:11:42.480: E/AndroidRuntime(2089):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(
```

Why m I getting this error any idea?

Comment: You are not new to SO. Post your code

Comment: "Body is limited to 30.000 characters you entered 47652"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your UI View tree is too deep.  `addFocusables` is recursive (obviously) into the `View` layout tree and Android has a fairly limited stack size.  Change your layout to do less nesting and more of a flat layout.  You may need to write a custom layout to get the layout you want without nesting.

Comment: Interesting.
What is "nesting" ? and what is a "flat layout"? can you tell me please?

Comment: See Romain Guy's excellent article on optimizing UI performance for more information:

http://www.curious-creature.org/docs/android-performance-case-study-1.html