# java.lang.StackOverflowError when pressing "next" on Android keyboard in Titanium Alloy TextField

Tags: android, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I have a form (several TextFields) in my Alloy app, when I click on "next"  while typing on a TextField I get a StackOverFlowError. My layout:

```
<ScrollView>
  `...

  <View class="viewrow" layout="horizontal">
    <Label class="ar-form-label">Salary</Label>
    <TextField class="ar-form-field" id="salary"></TextField>
  </View>

  <View class="bigger-viewrow" layout="horizontal">
    <Label class="form-label">Hours</Label>
    <TextField class="ar-form-field" id="hours"></TextField>
  </View>

  ...

</ScrollView>
```

What is wrong?

Stack Trace:
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [94150,96506] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.StackOverflowError; Titanium 3.5.1,2015/03/05 10:08,96875c9
[ERROR] TiApplication: java.lang.StackOverflowError
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:618)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.getFocusables(View.java:3559)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:109)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:93)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:476)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:3494)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4701)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:945)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1129)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isActive(InputMethodManager.java:542)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4184)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.draw(Vie
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1423)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
[ERROR] TiApplication:  at andr
-- End application log -------------------------------------------------------

Comment: stacktrace and java code might help getting an answer

Comment: I don't have any Java code, it is an Alloy app

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933319/scrollview-java-lang-stackoverflowerror

Comment: Already checked that one, If that was the case why it works perfect when not using that next button? 
If I use the "done" button on the last TextField it works.